# Opened my Eclipse for Android development after getting new libraries and got 100s of errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I am not completely sure what caused this to happen. Possibly it was because I got a number of updated from the SDK manager. But I opened my development environment and every line appears as an error.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Would anyone know how to debug this? I tried cleaning and restarting computer/Eclipse. That didn't help. Also it looks like everything is mis-configured now. Would anyone know where to even start debugging this issue?

Thank you!

Screen shot of my project properties:

[image]

Comment: It looks like your android libraries aren't in the build path for your project

Comment: @SamDufel yes seems like it. How would I configure that?

Comment: Start with Window -> Show View -> Problems

Comment: @Rajesh do you mean Show View -> properties? :) I am there

Comment: Menu Window -> Show View -> Problems or use ⌥⌘Q X in Mac. From your updated question, you have not selected a build target. Select one of those checkboxes in the Project Build Target list as @CommonsWare suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing your build target. Go to Project > Properties > Android and check the appropriate build target. That will at least clear up the "can't find `Button`" sorts of errors.

Comment: thank you :) I remember you. You helped me a million times before :)))) You are awesome! I am attaching a screen shot of what I got in properties on my original question. What should I do next?

Comment: I just updated my original question to also have the screen shot of the Android properties.

Comment: @Genadinik: There is a list of available build targets, labeled "Project Build Target". Choose one. Check it. Click OK.

Comment: Thank you that solved it - you are fantastic. Is there a way people can help you for all the help you give others?

Comment: Oh interesting. I would love to help promote it on my popular YouTube channel. @CommonsWare would you be interested in being a guest on my channel and talking about your products and services?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just tweeted to you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you were just updated the SDK then you have to be sure that you got the latest ADT. the SDK is updated from SDK manager, while the ADT is updated from the eclipse itself "Help > Check for update"